# Cassandra Spark Connector JavaDemo compile error

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Cassandra 2.2.8, JDK8, spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10, spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0-M3, cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0 and following
[Cassandra Spark Connector Example JavaDemo](https://gist.github.com/jacek-lewandowski/278bfc936ca990bee35a). This demo has to be fixed to compile with new 2.1 Connetcor API. I have fixed few things but this below one is stumping me:
 Compile Error at this line :

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, BigDecimal> allSalesRDD = joinedRDD.flatMap(new PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Sale, Product>>, Integer, BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, BigDecimal>> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Sale, Product>> input) throws Exception {
```

**Error:**

```
The method 
    flatMap(FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer,Tuple2<SparkJavaDemo.Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>,U>) in the type 
         AbstractJavaRDDLike<Tuple2<Integer,Tuple2<SparkJavaDemo.Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>,JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<SparkJavaDemo.
         Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>> is not applicable for the arguments (new 
         PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer,Tuple2<SparkJavaDemo.Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>,Integer,BigDecimal>(){})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMapToPair` instead of `flatMap` like below.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, BigDecimal> allSalesRDD = joinedRDD.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Sale, Product>>, Integer, BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, BigDecimal>> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Sale, Product>> input) throws Exception {
            Tuple2<Sale, Product> saleWithProduct = input._2();
            List<Tuple2<Integer, BigDecimal>> allSales = new ArrayList<>(saleWithProduct._2().getParents().size() + 1);
            allSales.add(new Tuple2<>(saleWithProduct._1().getProduct(), saleWithProduct._1().getPrice()));
            for (Integer parentProduct : saleWithProduct._2().getParents()) {
                allSales.add(new Tuple2<>(parentProduct, saleWithProduct._1().getPrice()));
            }
            return allSales.iterator();
        }
    });
```

I have created gist for updated code at https://gist.github.com/baghelamit/f2963d9e37acc55474559104f5f16cf1

Comment: Tried this **get a different error now**: `   public Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, BigDecimal>> call(Tuple2<Integer, Tuple2<Sale, Product>> input) `    The **return type is incompatible** with 
  PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer,Tuple2<SparkJavaDemo.Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>,Integer,BigDecimal>.call(Tuple2<Integer,Tuple
  2<SparkJavaDemo.Sale,SparkJavaDemo.Product>>)`

Comment: A separate compile error I get when I use core 3.1 java driver (works fine with 2.1) The resource type Session does not implement 
  java.lang.AutoCloseable                                                                 try (Session session = connector.openSession()) `

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml and java class for JavaDemo. Updated files are at https://gist.github.com/baghelamit/f2963d9e37acc55474559104f5f16cf1. Did you check that?

Comment: I was **seemingly able to compile** it fine finally- adding spark-sql and upgrading to core 3.12. The Session error was being caused by an offending dse.jar file. When i removed it - it compile fine. However at the package declaration itself eclipse is showing error: `The type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` When I try run it obviously gives error  `Unresolved compilation problem: @main` I do have scala 2.10. jar in my path.

Comment: The scala.reflect compile error was resolved by adding scala-reflect-2.11.jar. **Finally no compile errors**. Now runtime errors - hadoop/hdfs (added hadoop-common2.7.3.jar), then `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader` added spark-network-common_2.11.jar. **But the error persists** (I already had guava-16.0.jar)

Comment: For running that JavaDemo you need four dependencies in you pom.xml -spark-core, spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector and cassandra-driver-core. Check versions at pom.xml in gist I created. In eclipse you can do Maven > Update Project. I have tested and this is working fine for me.

Comment: Well it finally worked. I could finally align- eclipse, maven, and everything. Whew. Thanks